# cambiar el titulo de mi aplicación de escritorio c#

Tags: c#

como puedo cambiar el titulo de mi aplicación ya que me muestra la ruta de donde se esta ejecutando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el titulo de la aplicación de Consola puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
Console.Title = "Titulo de la aplicación deseable";
```

Puedes revisarte la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console.title(v=vs.110).aspx) para saber mas sobre esta propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

No sé debería responder algo que puede encontrarse tan facilmente en la documentación de microsoft pero lo que buscas es:

```
Console.Title = "Título consola";
```

Comment: sí se debe responder para evitar que otros lo hagan, si lo hacen de nuevo entonces marcala como duplicado a esta

Comment: Woops, ni me había dado cuenta, gracias por notarlo.